# How to suppress the z-axis legend in contour plots in Stata?

Tags: plot, stata

The title says it all. For example, the sample graph below, reproduced from Stata's first example of the `twoway contour` graph type, how would one suppress the vertical bar on the right with the five categories ranging from blue/7,600 to red/8,100. I know I can suppress (or alter) the "Depth (ft)" part by modifying the `ztitle` option.

```
sysuse sandstone
twoway contour depth northing easting
```

[image: Example Stata contour graph.]

If it matters, I am using Stata 14.2.

Comment: The usual `, legend(off)` is ignored. I think because the legend is constructed with special-purpose code.  You can remove the legend in the Graph Editor. Not sure why anyone would want to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `clegend` (rather than `legend`):

```
twoway contour depth northing easting, clegend(off) aspectratio(1)
```

This is documented under `help legend_options` or `help clegend_option`.